# What is diversity quotas?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

So I've been reading an article, and met the following statement:

> 66–76 percent of men support intellectually foundational texts above diversity quotas on reading lists; 44–66 percent of women support diversity quotas above foundational texts.

what do they mean by quotas here, related to the reading lists in academia?

I suppose its some kind of shallow *textbooks on broad topics* vs *fundamental books* in some domain?
Heres the article: https://quillette.com/2022/10/08/sex-and-the-academy/

Comment: Have you tried searching for "diversity quotas"? There are a lot of websites that explain what they are in broad terms, although more often applied to employees than authors.

Comment: yes, that is the problem. All google shows me is about quota as share/quantity, nothing about readings

Comment: "Diversity quotas" would mean we are required to choose texts written not only by white males, but also some written by women, Blacks, Hispanics, etc. But "intellectually foundational" means we try to choose the texts that best characterize the topic (even if it happens that those texts are all written by white males).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diversity quota is a requirement that at least a specified percentage (the quota) of some collection represent groups of people who have been disadvantaged (typically any group other than white men).

This is most often encountered in the context of hiring and college admissions, to ensure that minorities have opportunities for jobs and education. But in your quote, it refers to the authors of the books in the reading lists. A majority of men think that priority should be given to foundational texts, regardless of who the authors are; women are more likely  to say that diversity quotas should be used.

Comment: Thank you, its clear now!